# correct syntax from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench

Good Day!

what is the proper syntax query in MySQL? I'm getting error in mysql during execution (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*EmpCode AS CONCAT('EMP' , RIGHT(Concat('0000', CONVERT(EmpId, ' at line 3*)

```
CREATE TABLE tbEmployee
(
                EmpId INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY,
                EmpCode AS CONCAT('EMP' , RIGHT(Concat('0000', CONVERT(EmpId, CHAR(5))),5)) PERSISTED,
                EmployeeName VARCHAR(50),
                Age        INT,
                Gender VARCHAR(10)
)
```

Comment: `EmpId INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY,`  is a typo, it's wrong in either engines.

Comment: yes, just a mistake from posting. noted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL generated columns are either `VIRTUAL` (the default) or `STORED`, the latter corresponding to SQL Server's persisted.  Try this version:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbEmployee (
    EmpId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EmpCode VARCHAR(50) AS (CONCAT('EMP', LPAD(EmpId, 5, '0'))) STORED,
    EmployeeName VARCHAR(50),
    Age INT,
    Gender VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Note also that MySQL is a bit more lax with regards to casting numeric columns to text.  Also, we can use MySQL's `LPAD` function to left pad the employee ID with zeroes, to a width of 5 digits.

Comment: @matigo You're right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Additionally - `EmpId` must be explicitly assigned column, not autoincremented one.

Comment: it's getting an errorNr. 1064 "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (CONCAT('EMP', LPAD(EmpId, 5, '0'))) STORED,
    EmployeeName VARCHAR(50),
' at line 3"

Comment: @J.szareyo The create statement is working [in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c0dcd020a2e0cdb5afc306ba6db0ab0).  Maybe you are using an older version of MySQL which does not support computed columns.

Comment: I'm using the GUI MySQL Query Browser v 1.2.12 here in the office, but i have the 5.7 MySQL Workbench at home. I'll try it later